# Bootstrap/Tempalte not working when nested foreach is inserted in View using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have two tables in my program. The first one is `tbfininst` and the other is `tbsubmission`.
The `tbfininst` have a primary key of `fld_code` while the `tbsubmission` have a foreign key of `CODCODE`. It's a one to many relationship.
Now, I am displaying the rows of `tbfininst` in my blade.php. It looks like this.
[image]

Then, in the Submission (Periodicity) column, I want to insert how many rows from `tbsumission` does `tbfininst` have. By the way, the database is already created before I started. So I don't think I can use models or can i?

Anyways, in my controller, I tried using this code:

```
public function index()
{
   $fininst = DB::connection('portaldb')->table('tbfininst')->groupBy('fld_code')->get();

   $periodicity = DB::connection('portaldb')->table('tbsubmission')->select('CODCODE')->get();

   return view('pages/compliance', ['fininst' => $fininst, 'periodicity' => $periodicity]);
}
```

and in my blade.php:

```
@foreach($fininst as $fin)
<tr>
   <td>
     <center>        
       {{ $fin->fld_code }}
     </center>
   </td>
   <td>{{ $fin->fld_name }}</td>
   <td>
     @if ($fin->fld_status == 4)
        <p>Compliant</p>
     @else
        <p>Non-Compliant</p>
     @endif
   </td>
   <td>
     @if ($fin->fld_ip || $fin->fld_twofactor)
        <p>Compliant</p>
     @else
        <p>Non-Compliant</p>
     @endif
   </td>
   <td>
     @foreach($periodicity as $p)
        @if ($fin->fld_code == $p->CODCODE)
           {{$fin->fld_code}}
        @else
        @endif
     @endforeach
   </td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

When I inserted the `@foreach` of the periodicity, my blade.php output kinda not works.

[image]

I don't know why my template is not working. I just started using laravel two days ago and I'm still learning. I accept criticism, it will help me improved. Thank you.

Comment: It seems you need an increment variable, rather than outputting the value found. Use a variable like count++ when they are equal. Then after the loop output the value of count.

Comment: @CommonKnowledge, hello, thanks for your comment. I need the output value, it is required by the client

Answer (score 0):

You are just showing the matching values where you should be counting the matching values and showing them like this

```
@foreach($fininst as $fin)
   @php $count = 0; @endphp
        @foreach($periodicity as $p)
            @if ($fin->fld_code == $p->CODCODE)
               @php ++$count; @endphp
            @else
            @endif
         @endforeach
    <tr>
       <td>
         <center>        
           {{ $fin->fld_code }}
         </center>
       </td>
       <td>{{ $fin->fld_name }}</td>
       <td>
         @if ($fin->fld_status == 4)
            <p>Compliant</p>
         @else
            <p>Non-Compliant</p>
         @endif
       </td>
       <td>
         @if ($fin->fld_ip || $fin->fld_twofactor)
            <p>Compliant</p>
         @else
            <p>Non-Compliant</p>
         @endif
       </td>
       <td>

               {{$count}}

       </td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the count works but.. the layout of my blade is not working when I tried it. Then I got an error on my command prompt saying `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 63410176 bytes) in D:\Web-Applications\Test\portal\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Response.php on line 363` any idea what is this? Thank you so much!

Comment: You can try editing php.ini file and increase memory_limit = 2048M . also don't forget to restart phpserver

Comment: I tried editing the memory_limit of my xampp/php/php.ini, but nothing happens. Is this correct? or is there any php.ini I missed?

Comment: did you changed this file /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

Comment: I think I don't have a /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini, for I am in windows computer